# How to use form validations in bootstrap 4.3.1 and angular 8

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular8

I want to show an error message if answer not submit or answer max and min values incorrect.

Here is the code of html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header  bg-transparent border-success">
                <h3>15 questions</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <form [formGroup]="surveyQuestionForm">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label"> 3) Please rank the following features in order of importance,where 1 is the most important to you.?</label>
                                <div class="ml-3">
                                    <table>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>1. Location  <br/>
                                            <div class="invalid-feedback"
                                             *ngIf="surveyQuestionForm.get('q3').touched && surveyQuestionForm.get('q3').hasError('required')">Answer required</div>
                                             <div class="invalid-feedback"
                                             *ngIf="surveyQuestionForm.get('q3').touched && surveyQuestionForm.get('q3').hasError('max')">max value</div> 
                                             <div class="invalid-feedback"
                                             *ngIf="surveyQuestionForm.get('q3').touched && surveyQuestionForm.get('q3').hasError('min')">min value</div></td>

                                            <td><input type="number" style="width:40px;" id="q3_1"  
                                                [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': surveyQuestionForm.get('q3').errors && surveyQuestionForm.get('q3').touched}"
                                                    formControlName="q3" class="text-center" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>2. Confort </td>
                                            <td><input type="number" style="width:40px;" id="q3_1"  
                                                     class="text-center" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>3. Service </td>
                                            <td><input type="number" style="width:40px;" id="q3_1"  
                                                      class="text-center" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>4. Value for money </td>
                                            <td><input type="number" style="width:40px;" id="q3_1"  
                                                      class="text-center" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>


                                </div>
                            </div>



                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the typescript code

```
surveyQuestionForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.createForms();
  }
  createForms(): any {
    this.surveyQuestionForm = this.fb.group({
      q1: ['', Validators.required],
      q2: ['', Validators.required],
      q3: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(3)]],
      q4: ['', Validators.required],
      q5: ['', Validators.required],
      q6s: ['', Validators.required]
    } );
  }
```

I saw this [documentation](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/validation/) . But no idea how to use these classes.
I wasted many times to find an answer according to this problem,But I couldn't find any reference.Please help me to solve this.

thanks

Comment: Angular Validators: see https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes. This mean that if you has a .css like `.ng-invalid{border-color:red}`, when is invalid, the border-color of your input becomes red. tip: use web tools to see how is added this classes to your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem.In my case issue is,I missed "form-control" class in input tag.